# Ansible manage deployable files in multi environment project

Tags: ansible

In our projet, which has a `local`, `dev` and `prod` environment, we want to deploy a file `ourKeystore.p12`. This file must be present in those 3 environments, with the same name, but with a different content.

Here is how we manage our multiple environments :

```
/
- environments/
  - local/
    - group_vars/
      - vault.yml
      - vars.yml
    - hosts
  - dev/
    - group_vars/
      - vault.yml
      - vars.yml
    - hosts
  - prod/
    - group_vars/
      - vault.yml
      - vars.yml
    - hosts
```

To solve our problem, we found a way to deploy the correct `ourKeystore.p12` in the correct environment. The logic is found in the role which deploys `ourKeystore.p12` :

```
/
- roles/
  - our_role/
    - files/
      - local/
        - ourKeystore.p12
      - dev/
        - ourKeystore.p12
      - prod/
        - ourKeystore.p12
    - tasks/
      - main.yml
```

`main.yml` (simplified) :

```
- name: Copy keystore
  copy:
    src: "{{ current_environment }}/ourKeystore.p12"
    dest: path/to/ourKeystore.p12
```

It works, but it bothers us that environment dependent files are found in `roles/` instead of `environments/`.

What is the best approach to move ourKeystore.p12 from `roles/` to `environments/` ?
Ideally, we would like to have this, but it doesn't work :

```
/
- environments/
  - local/
    - files/
      - ourKeystore.p12
    - group_vars/
      - vault.yml
      - vars.yml
    - hosts
  - dev/
    - files/
      - ourKeystore.p12
    - group_vars/
      - vault.yml
      - vars.yml
    - hosts
  - prod/
    - files/
      - ourKeystore.p12
    - group_vars/
      - vault.yml
      - vars.yml
    - hosts
```

We didn't find anythong relevant in ansible documentation, neither on stackoverflow.

Best regards,
Vlad

Comment: How do you run the playbooks now?

Comment: hi, ```ansible-playbook ./our-playbook.yml -i environments/dev```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the special variable [*inventory_dir*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) to read the files in the roles. Put the declaration into the *group_vars/all*. For example,

```sh
shell> tree .
.
├── environments
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── files
│   │   │   └── ourKeystore.p12
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   └── all
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── prod
│       ├── files
│       │   └── ourKeystore.p12
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all
│       └── hosts
├── our-playbook.yml
└── roles
    └── our_role
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml
```

```yaml
shell> cat environments/dev/hosts 
srv.dev.net
shell> cat environments/dev/group_vars/all 
ourKeystore_path: "{{ inventory_dir }}/files/ourKeystore.p12"
shell> cat environments/dev/files/ourKeystore.p12 
dev content of ourKeystore.p12
```

```yaml
shell> cat environments/prod/hosts 
srv.prod.net
shell> cat environments/prod/group_vars/all 
ourKeystore_path: "{{ inventory_dir }}/files/ourKeystore.p12"
shell> cat environments/prod/files/ourKeystore.p12 
prod content of ourKeystore.p12
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/our_role/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('file', ourKeystore_path) }}"
shell> cat our-playbook.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - our_role
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook our-playbook.yml -i environments/dev/hosts 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [our_role : debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [srv.dev.net] => 
  msg: dev content of ourKeystore.p12

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
srv.dev.net: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook our-playbook.yml -i environments/prod/hosts 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [our_role : debug] **********************************************************************
ok: [srv.prod.net] => 
  msg: prod content of ourKeystore.p12

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
srv.prod.net: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for this complete answer. Also sorry for this long delay, I didn't have the opportunity to test your solution yet. It works as expected, but with a drawback : since ourKeystore.jks is a binary, and not a configuration text file, it displays warnings : [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse [..]/ourKeystore.p12 with ini plugin: [...]/keystore.p12:2: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: *�H��

Comment: To fix that, i moved files/ inside group_vars/, this folder is not parsed. Do you have a better way to do it ?

Comment: The main point in the answer is how to configure *ourKeystore_path*. In the question, you say ``we want to deploy a file ourKeystore.p12``. The warning states that **you deploy the file ourKeystore.p12**. Please open a new [mre] question when you can't parse it.